# CSS/HTML Raising Bars effect isn't working properly

Tags: html, css

I want this but instead of being upside down, i wanted from bottom to top direction. http://dabblet.com/gist/4405823

i tried the following code but it didn't worked, can u please help me in this code:

```
<style>
/** Pure CSS wave effect **/
div.wave{
    position: absolute
    ;
    width: 100%;
}
div.wave > span{
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: animate 1.5s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #B58900;  
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #F7877C;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #0E7DA8;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #C4EADF;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(5){
    background-color: #B4A4CB;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .8s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(6){
    background-color: #FBD92F;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(7){
    background-color: #268BD2;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(8){
    background-color: #859900;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(9){
    background-color: #BBFFFF;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
div.wave > span:nth-child(10){
    background-color: #FFE8E8;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.8s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate{
    to { height: 100px; }
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class='wave' style="position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%;height:60px">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it didn’t work? (And which browser were you testing in? That’s WebKit-only.)

Comment: I'm working with chrome , and it isn't moving as i want, from bottom to top instead of top bottom

Comment: I've posted a working modification.  In the future, please let us know what you have tried.

Comment: So like this, then? http://dabblet.com/gist/6001839

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you just also need to add a margin-top that is the same as the new height:

```
@keyframes animate{

    to { 
        height: 100px; 
        margin-top:100px; 
    }

}
```

Here's the modified, functioning wave: http://dabblet.com/gist/6001816